# how to explode key value pairs and use them in query

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, explode

in my laravel project i have a db field in which user can store the parameters that to be considered for sorting and also their orders. That is, the data table "config" contains a column value like this

```
status-desc,priority-asc,..etc
```

In here, when i write the query i need to use these values as the order by pairs.

```
ORDER BY status desc, priority asc
```

I can hard code this in the query code like the above because the sorting columns can be different based on the users entry.

i already exploded two criteria separately like this

```
$params = explode(',', $sort_param->config_value);
```

so that i got `$params[0] = status-desc and $params[1] = priority-asc ...`

But how can i again explode these and fetch and use them in the query for order by??

what i did so far is:

```
$countt = count($params);
for($prm=0;$prm<$countt;$prm++){
list($k, $v) = explode('-', $params[$prm]);
}
 echo $k.' '.$v;
```

The echo $k and $v displays `priority asc`

Comment: Your database design is wrong, serialising data into a single column is a violation of 1NF.  If a column in one table needs to store multiple values then that's a sure indication that you need to create a dependant table for that column instead.  Also, building queries based on external input is risky, to put it mildly.

Comment: why don't you consider your data as an associative array and then serialize it to save it on your db. then you can unserialize and do whatever you want.
as an example: `$value = array('status'=>'desc', 'priority'=>'asc');
$serialized = serialize ( $value );`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try

```
$tab = 'status-desc,priority-asc,value,string,demo';
$params = explode(',',$tab);
foreach($params as $v){
    $tab2[] = explode('-',$v);


}
$newTab = array_merge($params,$tab2);
print_r($newTab);
```

Comment: Hi..Thank you for ur answer.it solved my issue.. let me try using them in the query also..

Answer (score 0):

Try with this simple code

```
$tab = 'status-desc,priority-asc,value,string,demo';
list($statut,$priority,$value,$demo) = explode(',',$tab);
echo $statut ;
```